# SVG Favicon won't resize in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, favicon

I have an SVG that I want to use as Favicon for my React app. I used create-react-app if that matters.

If I use it on the actual website, inline, I am able to resize by adding or changing its `width="24px"` attribute:

```
<div>
  <svg
    id="LOGOS"
    width="100px"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
  >
//Paths and a lot of stuff within... 
</svg>
</div>
```

This is how my favicon looks on my index.html:

```
<link
  rel="icon"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/svg/main-logo-los-litros.svg"
  type="image/svg+xml"
/>
```

No matter what I do or try, the Favicon will always look very tiny. The only visible result I get is when I tweak the `viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"` to something else but it just disappears or looks like a pixel.

I have tried adding `width`, `height` only one of those, `sizes` and nothing seems to work!

How can I get my SVG to scale up to look better as favicon?

Answer (score 0):

Your SVG should only need the `viewBox` attribute and the content to be within that viewBox. When you don't have a viewBox defined, width and height will not scale the graphic but adjust the viewBox (sort of can look like cropping if too small).

When you have a `viewBox` attribute defined, and define both width and height, the content within that viewBox region is scaled to fit within the width and height bounds, or based on the rules of `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.

However, when you only provide one dimension, then the SVG will be instructed to scale to that width or height while maintaining the aspect ratio.

---

Regarding a favicon, you have not clarified what "tiny" means. If you're on a regular 96 DPI or so display and the favicon for a tab only has 16x16 pixels, then it would be scaled down to this.

If your graphic content does not fully fill the viewBox bounds, then that extra white-space is part of the scaled content, such that if you only used 25% of the space, your graphic would be 8x8 pixels in the 16x16 pixels rendered favicon. That could be 4px of padding around the graphic (if only using 25% of viewBox) if you centered it within the viewBox.